# Read Data From MongoDB When Document Structure Is Different

Tags: c#, mongodb

We are currently working on a .NET Core application and we are using MongoDB for it. I am using .NET Driver to access the data. All the data we are saving in a collection has different types of data structure.

For example, it has first document which has Name, Phone and a Payload which has embedded document in which we are saving address:

```
{
    "Name": "TestName",
    "Phone": "23846787",
    "Payload": {
        "Address": "TestAddress",
        "City": "TestCity"
    },
    "Active": true
}
```

Then in the same collection we have another document which has Name, Phone and a Payload which is completely different from first one:

```
{
    "Name": "TestName2",
    "Phone": "54568765",
    "Payload": {
        "Weight": "70",
        "Age": "45",
        "Gender": "Female"
    }
}
```

Now when we use .NET driver to get both of these records, we get an error because it cannot cast the embedded document into an object (as it doesnt know about the object). We need to tell it, which type of object  is the embedded document. But we dont want to do it because we have several types of payload we want to save. I tried using discriminator "_t" but it didn't help.

Can someone please suggest how we can read the data when we have different elements in the document and also has embedded documents?

Comment: Welcome! It's a bit hard to tell exactly what you're doing, as you haven't included any code (aside from sample JSON data) - it would help if you edited your question to include relevant code. That said: Have you tried querying as `BSonDocument`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Daivd. I have tried using BsonDocument but the problem with that is when I retrieve the document it gives me errors. Once I convert my object to BsonDocument, AsBsonDocument has document I want but for all the properties like AsBoolean, AsBsonArray, AsBsonSymbol etc. it is giving error: object.AsBoolean threw an exception of type System.InvalidCastException (this one is for boolean). For AsBsonArray it is giving error: object.AsBsonArray threw an exception of type System.InvalidCastException.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a convention indicating that the client must ignore the elements that it is unable to map:

```
var conventionPack = new ConventionPack
{
    new IgnoreExtraElementsConvention(true)
};
ConventionRegistry.Register("conventions", conventionPack, _ => true);

var client = new MongoClient(options)...
```